# xml data handling regex find replace with conditional values

Tags: regex, xml, replace, conditional-statements

I got a xml file which looks like this

```
<DocumentElement>
<Table1>
<Date>2013-08-24</Date>
<Time>00:07:23</Time>
<Type>in</Type>
<Number>393483419761</Number>
<Name>Marc</Name>
<Message>Lorem ipsum</Message>
</Table1>
<Table1>
<Date>2013-08-24</Date>
<Time>00:09:09</Time>
<Type>out</Type>
<Number>1215468498561</Number>
<Name>Marc</Name>
<Message>Lorem ipsum</Message>
</Table1>
<DocumentElement>
```

What I want to do is Check the Date Value and if the Month is 01, add `<Month>january</Month>` after `</Date>`, and if month is 02 add `<Month>february</Month>` and so on.
So what I got so far is either:

```
<Date>(\d{4})-01-(\d{2})</Date>
<Date>$1-01-$2</Date>
<Month>january</Month>
```

or i'd like to do something like:

```
<Date>(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})</Date>

if ($2 = 01) {
<Date>$1-$2-$3</Date>
<Month>january</Month>
}

elseif ($2 = 02) {
<Date>$1-$2-$3</Date>
<Month>february</Month>
}
```

whats the usual way to handle and manipulate data like this?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for XSLT than a regex. If you're interested, I can take a stab at writing it.

Comment: im already using xslt to manipulate the tags and stuff but as far as i know xslt is not capeable of regex, so i have no clue how im supposed to do it with that.

Comment: You don't need a regex to check if ```substring(trim(text(date)), 6, 2) = '01'```, it's just slightly ugly. But the parsing and encoding are all handled for you. exslt also has date functions.

Comment: ok i think i know what you're saying. i have to regex other stuff to in this file, so for me it doesnt mather if i can do it with python or xslt, but if it was only about this date thing, your solution looks like the cleanest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally if you are parsing XML you would use a real parser instead of regular expressions. But in your particular case it is a very simple operation you want do do. Go over each line, print it, and if the current line is a date, extract the month and print an additional line.

Here's an example python script that does that.

```py
import re
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
          "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
with open(your_xml_file) as f:
    for line in f:
        print line
        match = re.search(r'<Date>\d{4}-(?P<month>\d{2})-\d{2}</Date>', line)
        if match is not None:
            print months[int(match.group('month')) - 1]
```

Note, however that this will fail as soon as you insert whitespace or add something else like attributes to Date. That's why it's better to use a real parser. But if your format is exactly like you stated, then it is faster to just write a small throw away script like this.

Comment: Not just whitespace, but also handling entities and attributes on Date.

Comment: Indeed! Mentioned attributes now too.

Comment: thanks alot! unfourtunatly i have no clue about python i dont even know how to run it, but i'll make some research. i'm sure i'll work that out

Comment: well i figured everything out, i understand your code. i just can't get it to write the result in a new file.

Answer (score 0):

so just for the record this is my final code which adds another regex substitution and outputs everything in a new file:

```
x = 'marco_2013_24_08' #filename without extension

import re
months = ["<Month>gennaio</Month>", "<Month>febbraio</Month>", "<Month>marzo</Month>", "<Month>aprile</Month>", "<Month>maggio</Month>", "<Month>giugno</Month>", "<Month>luglio</Month>",
          "<Month>agosto</Month>", "<Month>settembre</Month>", "<Month>ottobre</Month>", "<Month>novembre</Month>", "<Month>dicembre</Month>"]
import sys
sys.stdout = open('_' + x + 'regexed.xml', 'w')
with open(x + '.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        im = re.sub(r'<Message>Image\:\ .+\/(IMG.+\.jpg)<\/Message>',r'<Image href="Bilder/\1"></Image>',line)
        print im
        mm = re.search(r'<Date>\d{4}-(?P<month>\d{2})-\d{2}</Date>', line)
        if mm is not None:
            print months[int(mm.group('month')) - 1]
```